# Typescript ESM module resolution not working with nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I have a small project and I'm switching to esm. For the switch I did the following:

1. Changed `type` in package.json to "module"
2. Changed `module` and `moduleResolution` in tsconfig.json to `esnext` and `nodenext`.
3. Added `tsnode.esm` with value `true` in tsconfig.json.
4. Changed imports in the source codes.
5. Added `imports` to package.json and `paths` to tsconfig.json

These are my config files:

**package.json:**

```json
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "type": "module",
    "main": "src/app.ts",
    "imports": {
        "#src/*": "./build/*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rm -r build; npm cache clean --force",
        "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=development && npm run start:dev || npm run build && npm run start:prod",
        "start:dev": "NODE_PATH=src nodemon --exec node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/app.ts",
        "build": "tsc -P tsconfig.production.json",
        "start:prod": "NODE_PATH=build node -r dotenv/config ./build/app.js",
        "prettier": "prettier --write './**/*.{ts,js}'",
        "test": "NODE_PATH=src NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' mocha --exit -r dotenv/config ./src/**/*.test.{ts,mts,cts,js,mjs,cjs}",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.mjs,.mts ./src"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": [
                "pretty-quick --staged && npm run lint && npm test"
            ]
        }
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.1.1",
        "@types/boom": "^7.3.0",
        "@types/chai": "^4.3.5",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/hapi__boom": "^9.0.1",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
        "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
        "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
        "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.36",
        "@types/morgan": "^1.9.4",
        "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
        "@types/validator": "^13.7.17",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.9",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
        "eslint": "^8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.5",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "husky": "^8.0.3",
        "if-env": "^1.0.4",
        "mocha": "^10.2.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.1.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@adminjs/express": "^6.0.0",
        "@adminjs/mongoose": "^4.0.0",
        "@hapi/boom": "^10.0.1",
        "@sentry/integrations": "^7.54.0",
        "@sentry/node": "^7.54.0",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^7.54.0",
        "@typegoose/typegoose": "^11.2.0",
        "adminjs": "^7.0.6",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
        "mongoose": "^7.2.2",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "validator": "^13.9.0",
        "winston": "^3.9.0"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "build",
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "paths": {
            "#src/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
        "transpileOnly": true
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.js"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "./build"]
}
```

### The Problem

Now the problem is when I add `imports` to package.json file, I can run npm build and it would create a build folder and when I run the project inside the folder, all `#src/` imports will be mapped to build folder as expected. But when I want to run `npm run start:dev` which is a live run which restarts on file change with `nodemon` (because after changing to esm I couldn't use `ts-node-dev` for some reason it didn't work!), It raises an error like this:

```err
/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module '/usr/app/build/admin/admin.js' imported from /usr/app/src/app.ts
    at finalizeResolution (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)
    at moduleResolve (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)
    at /usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:218:35
    at entrypointFallback (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:168:34)
    at /usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:217:14
    at addShortCircuitFlag (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:409:21)
    at resolve (/usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:197:12)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
```

As you can see it still maps `#src` to `build` folder while I need it to map it to `src` folder because I want it to run the source with `ts-node` and not build it first.

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you doing the imports thing? It seems that's the thing causing you troubles and it doesn't look like a good idea

Comment: You don’t need the `imports` in package.json. The fact you are mapping it to your build means you probably want `exports` instead.

Comment: @Axnyff I used this link to migrate to esm: https://dev.to/logto/migrate-a-60k-loc-typescript-nodejs-repo-to-esm-and-testing-become-4x-faster-12-5f82

Although in the github repo they don't use `imports` even though they have mentioned it in this article.

If I don't use `imports`, then how could I run the built version of the code and map `#src` to `build` folder?

Comment: @morganney I didn't understand why I need `exports`? This is a project and it wouldn't be used as a module. So I guess I don't need `exports`, right?

Comment: @Hamed once you have built your code you can run directly the built file

Comment: @Axnyff If i build the project, then how would it resolve `import '#src/user/index.js';`?
I mean it doesn't know where to map `#src`

Comment: Isn't your start:prod command doing the right thing, directly calling the build file: build/app.js ?

Comment: @Axnyff it is but inside the file `build/app.js` I have some imports that start with `#src` which must be mapped to the right folder i.e. `build` which it can't resolve